# SQL COUNT DISTINCT on range partitions

Tags: sql, count, presto, partition

I'm trying to query using Presto SQL on counting specific active ids on a given range. I have a table that contains month, date, id. If an id is on that table for that specific date, then it is considered active.

I need to know if its possible to COUNT DISTINCT ids for ranges that vary depending on the date.

What I'm trying to get as output (since logic needed for my work) is the for a specific date (ie. June 14, 2023), it will pull active users from June (start of month) to June 14.

I've tried using DENSE_RANK since I cant use Partitions on COUNT but nonetheless the logic still doesnt apply.

Output should be example :

```
  Grass_Month | Grass_date  | active_users
2023-06-01    | 2023-06-01  | 234 -- active unique users on June 1
2023-06-01    | 2023-06-02  | 483-- active unique users from June 1 to June 2
```

Comment: How do we know when an id is NOT active? I think you need to provide `sample data` and then the `expected result` from that sample - only then will we really understand what you are asking for. Be sure we understand how to identify active & inactive conditions in that sample and result. Do not use images, copy/paste data as simple tables or as SQL inserts - OR - create sample tables as a fiddle site like https://dbfiddle.uk or sqlfiddle.com

Comment: btw: I think you can use the `over` clause with `count` hence you should be able to use `partition by`, but you also would have access to `frame` see: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html (it does not specifically mention `count` on this page but there is an example using `sum`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the your_table with actual name of your table.The start_date and end_date should be replaced with the specific range you want to query.

Example:

```
SELECT
  start_date,
  end_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS active_users
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.date AS start_date,
    t2.date AS end_date,
    t1.id
  FROM
    your_table t1
  JOIN
    your_table t2 ON t2.date <= t1.date
) subquery
GROUP BY
  start_date,
  end_date
ORDER BY
  start_date,
  end_date;
```